# MySQL created_by or updated_last-by

Tags: mysql, oracle, database-design, trigger

I've been giving the task of taking SQL DDL from data modeler and to transcribe it into mySQL for an internship. The only thing I cannot figure out is how to take

```
Created_By VARCHAR2(30) DEFAULT USER,
```

and turn that into sql my resolution was just to do a trigger but now the trigger doesn't work

```
    /* Triggers for User Creation */
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER menu_creator_tr 
BEFORE INSERT ON Menu 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    NEW.Created_By = USER();
END 
DELIMITER;
```

it states that NEW.Created_By is missing a colon. I am very confused now. Just started learning sql and so i am lost. Some help for both problems is what I am looking for to learn, but a help on either or will help me finish this. I really need to know this though for I have more columns that are similar.

Comment: Is the question about MySQL or Oracle? These are two distinct DBMS, and the solution will probably be different.

Comment: Oracle migrating to mySQL.

Comment: Oh I see. So the problem is that Oracle allows the `DEFAULT` value of a column to be the `USER()` function while MySQL does not.

Comment: yes mySQL only allows constants but I got it to work using a trigger. I posted my solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Okay I figured it out. No Need for Delimiters because it is technically one line or one statement and only needs one semicolon. Also make sure to notice that one is for before an `Insert` and one before an `Update`. I believe that `SET` was also necessary.

```
CREATE TRIGGER CREATE_BY_MENU_TR 
BEFORE INSERT ON MENU 
FOR EACH ROW 
SET NEW.Create_By = CURRENT_USER();

CREATE TRIGGER CREATE_BY_MENU_TR 
BEFORE UPDATE ON MENU 
FOR EACH ROW 
SET NEW.Last_Update_By = CURRENT_USER();
```

The `Create_By` and `Last_Update_By` are just columns of data type varchar.